# How to serialize forms and post using jQuery Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile, serialization

I'm trying to remove records from my DB......
this is how my form looks like.........

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("RemoveDoctor", "Doctor", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "form" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Name)
    <div class="form-actions no-color">
        <input type="submit" value="Delete" class="btn btn-default" id="submit" /> |

    </div>
}
```

I'm trying to get these records from the view and pass to my controller Action method............................. i'm trying to serialize this form and send it to that action method as following...................

> var jsonObj = $('#form').serialize();

it serialize the form put my Ajax POST function wont run with that result......
it just gives me an error!!!!................. I just need to pass that serialize value to my Action method............... This is how my Script looks like.....................

```
$('#submit').click(function () {

     var jsonObj = $('#form').serialize();
     alert(jsonObj);

     $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: '../Doctor/RemoveDoctor',
           data: JSON.stringify({ "doctor": jsonObj }),
           success: function (data) {
                 alert(data.Message);
           },
           error: function () {
                  alert("Error!!!");
           }
      });
      return false;

});
```

This is how my action method looks like....................

```
  public ActionResult RemoveDoctor(DoctorModel doctor)
  {
      bool confirmationResult = doctorManager.RemoveDoctor(doctor.Id);
      string displayMessage = string.Empty;
      if (confirmationResult == true)
           displayMessage = "You have successfully removed your record!!";
      else
           displayMessage = "Error!! Some Thing Went Wrong, Please Try Again!!";

      return Json(new { Message = displayMessage });

  }
```

I'm trying to send this 'displayMessage' to my jQuery code........ please some give me an idea how to solve this....... thanks!!!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
 $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: '../Doctor/RemoveDoctor',
           data: $('#form').serialize(),
           success: function (data) {
                 alert(data.Message);
           },
           error: function () {
                  alert("Error!!!");
           }
      });
```

It will serialize your form.

Use only `$('#form').serialize()` for serialization.

**Edit**

If you don't want to refresh page then you should use `type="button"` instead `type="submit"`

And

You should do this also

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult RemoveDoctor(DoctorModel doctor)
  {
      //...................
      return Json(new { Message = displayMessage } , JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

  }
```

And change ajax error function to this (For getting error )

```
error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
{
  alert("Error: "+errorThrown+" , Please try again");   
}
```

Comment: One more thing -- try this `url: "@Url.Action("RemoveDoctor", "Doctor")"` in ajax  @Dayan

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71650/discussion-between-manoj-and-dayan).